# the method ceilingEntry(MyTime) is undefined for the type TreeMap<MyTime,Integer>

Tags: java, gwt

I'm working on a GWT project.
I'm building a class that holds a TreeMap as a class member.
The definition of the member:

```
private TreeMap<MyTime, Integer> VisitMap;
```

The Keys of the treeMap are objects of a type I've built before called "MyTime" (which implement Comparable interface), and the values are simple integers.

At one of the functions in the class I try to find the ceilingEntry using a MyTime object that was given as a key input.

```
public void getCeil(MyTime _MT)
{
    int myVal = VisitMap.ceilingEntry(_MT).getValue();
}
```

For some reason I get this error message:

```
the method ceilingEntry(MyTime) is undefined for the type TreeMap<MyTime,Integer>.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to use this in client-side code?

GWT JRE emulation doesn't support all of the JRE classes. 
According to [GWT 1.6 docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/RefJreEmulation.html#Package_java_util), only following methods of treemap are supported:

> TreeMap(), TreeMap(Comparator), TreeMap(Map), TreeMap(SortedMap),
>   clear(), comparator(), containsKey(Object), entrySet(), firstKey(),
>   get(Object), headMap(K), lastKey(), put(K, V), remove(Object), size(),
>   subMap(K, K), tailMap(K)

**EDIT:**

Just checked [GWT 2.3 docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html#Package_java_util), and the support seems to be same as GWT 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 1.5 ? ceilingEntry is only available in 1.6, looks like.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#ceilingEntry%28K%29
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#ceilingEntry%28K%29

Comment: Didn't help :( Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `Map` of `MyTime` to `Integer`, which I assume holds the ceiling for the MyTime. So, shouldn't you just look up the Integer corresponding to the MyTime?

Also, getter usually returns a value.

I think your method should be just this:

```
public int getCeil(MyTime _MT) {
    return VisitMap.get(_MT);
}
```

Comment: Yep, but the problem is that I can't access that MyTime from the first place